# PID to generate different order Systems

Tags: transfer-function, pid-controller

I am looking at an old exam question and I am wondering giving a certain `G(s)` how can I choose the points of the zeros in a PID Controller to have a second order response for small values of K and a first order response for large values of K. So far I have found the transfer function but I am unsure how to determine the zeros. If anyone could even provide an explanation I would be very grateful!

[image]

For a) finding the transfer function I get [image]

From here I can see that if K is small I will get a second order response, and if K is large I can see where I would get the first order response.

What I do not understand is how do I find the Zeroes (a and b) for the PID to give the desired response?

Edit:
I apologize, both K and k are the same I will fix that. In the question for small K the system should have a second order response to a step input and a first order response for large values of K.

Comment: What do you want for non-small values of K? Is "K" the same as "k"?

Comment: I have updated my question in answer your questions.

Comment: Try again - hint - 3rd line from the top!

Comment: In the problem statement?

Comment: Also if k is small don't you actually get a third order response?

Comment: I assumed that if K is small you end up with G(s)/1 giving the second order response but if K is large the system would be of higher order would it not?

Comment: "... small values of K and a first order response for small values of K" - how many times do I need to ask you about this part of your question?

Comment: I completely missed that! I apologize

Comment: If k is large everything appears to cancel it seems looking at your formula.

Comment: K would be large enough that the other terms do not matter and when a step is applied we end up with simply 1/s

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm just not seeing that - if k is large then forget about the "1" bit. Then, unless I'm going blind or stupid (too early in the day but not unheard of)  you are left with numerator and denominator that are exactly equal. I can't see how there can be a spare s in the denominator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLTF is: $$\small \frac{Y(s)}{R(s)}=\frac{K(s+a)(s+b)}{s^3+(2+K)s^2+(2+K(a+b))s+abK}$$

To produce a 1st order TF, we would like \$\small (s+a)(s+b)\$ to cancel two of the roots in the denominator. Exact cancellation is not normally attainable, so let's go for approximate.

Thus, write the 'ideal' denominator as \$\small(s+a)(s+b)(s+c)\$, and find the value of \$\small c\$ that approximates this denominator when \$\small K\$ is large.

Expanding \$\small(s+a)(s+b)(s+c)\$ and comparing denominators:

\$\small s^3+(a+b+c)s^2+(ab+bc+ca)s+abc\: \approx\: s^3+(2+K)s^2+(2+K(a+b))s+abK\$

Comparing constant terms, \$\small abc=abK\$, hence \$\small c\rightarrow K\$, and substituting:

\$\small s^3+(a+b+c)s^2+(ab+bc+ca)s+abc\: \approx\: s^3+(a+b+K)s^2+(ab+K(a+b))s+abK\$

Now, let \$\small K\$ become large, so that:

\$\small [(a+b)+K]\approx [2+K]\$ and \$\small [ab+K(a+b)]\approx [2+K(a+b)]\$

Hence we have the denominator:\$\small\ (s^2+(a+b)s+ab)(s+K)\$, and the required 1st order CLTF is:
$$\small \frac{Y(s)}{R(s)}\approx \frac{K}{s+K}$$

To illustrate, consider \$\small a=1\$; \$\small b=1\$; \$\small K=100\$.

The CLTF is:
$$\small \frac{Y(s)}{R(s)}= \frac{100(s^2+2s+1)}{s^3+102s^2+202s+100}$$

It can be seen that \$\small (s^2+2s+1)\$ is an approximate factor of \$\small (s^3+102s^2+202s+100)\$ [it's an exact factor of \$\small (s^3+102s^2+201s+100)\$], giving the 1st order CLTF: $$\small\frac{Y(s)}{R(s)}\approx\frac{100}{s+100}$$

Analysis for small \$\small K\$ can proceed similarly.